# Is it possible to retrieve insight data for comments and likes of CAROUSEL_ALBUM using Instagram's Graph API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I tried to retrieve insight data for comments and likes of CAROUSEL_ALBUM using the following endpoint, but I encountered the following error.

get comments

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{media-id}/insights?metric=reach,saved,comments&period=day&since=1709335531&access_token={access_token}
```

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Incompatible metric (comments) with the media",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "AXS"
   }
}
```

get likes

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{media-id}/insights?metric=reach,saved,likes&period=day&since=1709335531&access_token={access_token}
```

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Incompatible metric (likes) with the media",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "AKkUu"
   }
}
```

I can retrieve reach and saved, but I cannot retrieve insight data for comments and likes of CAROUSEL_ALBUM. How can I retrieve insight data for comments and likes of CAROUSEL_ALBUM?

Comment: `comments` and `likes` are only available on Reels and Posts. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights#metrics-2 explicitly says on post metrics: _"The following metrics are available on image and video IG Media published as a Post. Album carousels and IGTV are not supported."_